# Python debugger in spyder stops at line 2

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

when i am trying to debug my code the debugger stops at line 2 and doenst respond to any commands (like go to next line).

I am using python 3.9.7.

This is what the console looks like:
[image]

If I try to stop the debugger this happens:
[image]
The only thing I can do then is close the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had recently the same problem (using Python 3.8) and the solution was to revert an recent upgrade of qtconsole from 5.1.1 to 5.2.2. In case you use conda, the command to revert would be "conda install  qtconsole=5.1.1".

Comment: Worked perfectly for my python version. Thanks! I tried this in one virtual enviroment now. If I downgrade it in base will this affect all other enviroments or do I need to do this every time?

Comment: Thank you! This has worked for me as well. I had the same issue and now using this answer it has been resolved.

Comment: It also worked for me after I re-opened Anaconda. Thanks!