# Spyder debugger unable to step past the first line

Tags: debugging, anaconda, spyder

```
1    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
-->  """
3    Created on Tue Feb 15 20:14:21 2022
4    
5    @author: me
6    """
7    import pandas as pd
```

I get stuck on line 2. Clicking on "Run Current Line" does nothing. None of the other tools work either. I cannot continue to next breakpoint or anything.

When I click on "Stop Debugging" I get the following message:

```
--KeyboardInterrupt--
For copying text while debugging, use Ctrl+Shift+C
```

I'm honestly at a complete loss as to what is going on. I just noticed this today and have no clue how to alleviate this. Does this require me to reinstall Anaconda?

Here are a few versions:

```
conda 4.11.0
anaconda-client 1.9.0
spyder 5.1.5
python 3.8.12
```

If you need more versions please let me know.

Comment: Have tried downgrading which also failed. Unclear how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing the exact same issue. I want to debug my code in spyder. When I am putting my code in debug mode by pressing the ctrl+F5, the execution is stuck on line 2. Moreover, when I am trying to stop the debug mode the same "--KeyboardInterrupt--For copying text while debugging, use Ctrl+Shift+C" statement is coming.

Comment: I tried the answer provided in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102782/python-debugger-in-spyder-stops-at-line-2. This has resolved my issue.

Comment: @ankushjamthikar  please - do it as answer?

Answer (score 3):

conda install qtconsole=5.1.1

This solved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

it is said to be a bug.
you need to upgrade to a later version.

I have the same problem.
and windows spyder 5.1.5 works while linux spyder 5.1.5 not working.